# PHP - Remove arrays by its value

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the `array` i have , and i wanted to modify it the way i needed.

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                        [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                        [timestamp] => 1402593151
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                        [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                        [timestamp] => 1402593194
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593249
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593250
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593257
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593282
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593286
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593303
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593308
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593309
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ip] => 127.0.0.1
                    [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
                    [timestamp] => 1402593309
                )

        )

)
```

i need the above `array` parents to remove , and the child values saved, like this one :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
            [timestamp] => 1402593151
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
            [timestamp] => 1402593194
        )   
   [2] => Array
       (
           [ip] => 127.0.0.1
           [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
           [timestamp] => 1402593249
       )     
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
            [timestamp] => 1402593303
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
            [timestamp] => 1402593308
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
            [timestamp] => 1402593309
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [php_session] => d9r2qfeiheo0gfklcq7vbj9nq7
            [timestamp] => 1402593309
        )
)
```

after this , i want to modify the result `array` to remove any key that have the same `ip`
 and `php_session` value. any ideas out there ?

Comment: Just curious, but have you tried to solve this? Perhaps even a simple foreach loop?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn , yes , i did some research about it , i found tons of answers but non of the answers solved my issue. most helpful answer i got was the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` function , but still not doing exact what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just make 2 foreach loops like so:

```
<?php
$beginArray = array(
    array(
        array(
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'php_session' => 'abcde',
            'timestamp' => 'abce'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'php_session' => 'abcde',
            'timestamp' => 'abce'
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'php_session' => 'abcde',
            'timestamp' => 'abce'
        )
    ),
);


foreach($beginArray as $array) {

    foreach($array as $arr) {
        $resultArray[] = $arr;
    }

}
var_dump($resultArray);
?>
```

Anyways: Take better names for the variables. :)

Comment: Nice one , but what about matching `arrays` with its value ? something like `remove array where ip == 127.0.0.1 and php_session == abcde ` ? and what do u mean by `Take better names for the variables` , do i set these bad or wrong or something?

Comment: No haha, I mean don't take my variable names '$array' '$resultArray' '$arr'.

Comment: You will probably have to work with array_search() then.

Comment: if you have any idea about it , any way to get it work, i did alots of research about it and still cant figure it out :D

Comment: Google array_search() and try it out.